# Scanning QR Codes on android without java

Tags: android, cordova, camera, mobile-website, qr-code

I just mad a app which uses phongeab + phonegab BarcodeScanner Plugin. But for this webapp i need to install the app on my phone. Is it possible to make a webapp which can scan qr-codes without the need to be installed on the phone ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, scanning requires access to the camera which the browser will not allow.

Comment: some days ago i was one the mobile version of ebay, and there was a button to call the selling guy. So this webapp access my native function to make a call without me installing any native stuff ? how does that work ?

Comment: It is just a `tel:` hyperlink. The browser has nothing to do with the call. Clicking the link just tells the platform to open the dialer, which can of course make a call.

Comment: so the only native stuff you can access via webapp is the call functionality ?

Comment: In that case, you are not really accessing anything *via* the browser. The browser is triggering an external app. This is no more or less native than the solution I posted; same sort of mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

This is the closest you can get from just the browser, but it works pretty well:

http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningFromWebPages

Comment: if i get it right, for this one i need to install a native barcodescanner ?

Comment: Yes. The browser could never do this by itself.